# moment.js give different time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

i have this code and working good but given more 2 hours then my time

```
$('.given_date').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var utcTime = $this.data('gamestart');
    var utcTimes = $this.data('gameends');

    var startTime = moment(utcTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    var endTimes = moment(utcTimes, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    var endTime = moment.utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

    var x = startTime.diff(endTime, 'minutes');
    var y = endTimes.diff(endTime, 'minutes');

    switch (true) {
        case (x > 30):
            var localTime = moment.utc(utcTime).toDate();
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").text(moment(localTime).format('LT').replace("PM", "مساء").replace("AM", "صباحا"));
            localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            $this.countdowntimer({
                dateAndTime : localTime
            });
            break;
        case (x > 0 ):
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").html('<div class="">workin soon </div>');
            var localTime = moment.utc(utcTime).toDate();
            localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            $this.countdowntimer({
                dateAndTime : localTime
                });
            break;
        case (y > 0 ):
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").html('<div class="blink_txt fximres1"> working now</div>');
            break;
        default:
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").html('<div class="fximres1"> job end</div>');
            break;
    }
});
```

i try use .zone("Africa/Cairo") to get my real time like this

```
$('.given_date').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var utcTime = $this.data('gamestart');
    var utcTimes = $this.data('gameends');

    var startTime = moment(utcTime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    var endTimes = moment(utcTimes, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
    var endTime = moment.utc().zone("Africa/Cairo").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");

    var x = startTime.diff(endTime, 'minutes');
    var y = endTimes.diff(endTime, 'minutes');

    switch (true) {
        case (x > 30):
            var localTime = moment.utc(utcTime).zone("Africa/Cairo").toDate();
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").text(moment(localTime).zone("Africa/Cairo").format('LT').replace("PM", "مساء").replace("AM", "صباحا"));
            localTime = moment(localTime).zone("Africa/Cairo").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            $this.countdowntimer({
                dateAndTime : localTime
            });
            break;
        case (x > 0 ):
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").html('<div class=""> working soon</div>');
            var localTime = moment.utc(utcTime).zone("Africa/Cairo").toDate();
            localTime = moment(localTime).zone("Africa/Cairo").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            $this.countdowntimer({
                dateAndTime : localTime
                });
            break;
        case (y > 0 ):
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").html('<div class="blink_txt fximres1"> working now</div>');
            break;
        default:
            $this.parent().find(".stsrt58").html('<div class="fximres1"> job end</div>');
            break;
    }
});
```

only cooldown working good but not print state time on hrml working soon and working now and job end in my page

what is the problem in code please

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide minimum working example. Your code sample is way too long. Also please state the problem description more clearly.

Comment: You would like to get the time in Cairo, but the time displayed is two hours later. Do I understand you correctly? What do you mean by cooldown?

Comment: Also here's a longer description of jakub.g's suggestion: [mcve]

Comment: yes @Cecilia code give +2 hours